# Symfony Propel Pager - what is the proper way to send it a custom MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, symfony1, propel, pager

Here is the query I need to run

> SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOWER(table.url), '/',  3), 'www.', ''), 'http://', '') AS domain FROM table GROUP BY domain

But I'm having trouble passing a query like this to the Propel pager as criteria. I was hoping this would work.

> $criteria->addSelectColumn('SUBSTRING_INDEX(' . TablePeer::URL . ', \'/\',  3) AS table');

But unfortunately it doesn't. Any ideas how I could pass this using a criteria method?

**UPDATE**

For those interested, this is what ended up working, thanks!

> $criteria->addAsColumn('domain', 'SUBSTRING_INDEX(' . TablePeer::URL . ', \'/\',  3)');
>   $criteria->addGroupByColumn('domain');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use some combination of `Criteria::CUSTOM` and `addAsColumn` in your criteria object - youll obviously also need to use `doSelectRs` (<= 1.2) or `doSelectStmt` (>=1.3) Im not sure what the exact formulation would be but this might get you in the right direction (note the link is for 1.2 so update sysntaxt/api as needed for 1.3 or 1.4).

http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2009/07/21/propel-criteria-on-custom-columns-with-addascolumn/

Comment: "addAsColumn" seems to be what I was looking for, this works, thanks!